# Will local minimums and maximums of magnitude response of a real LTI system always correspond exactly to the phase angles of the zeroes and poles?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-transform, signal-processing, z-transform

Will the normalized frequencies corresponding to the local minimums and maximums for the frequency magnitude response $|H(e^{j \omega})|$ of an linear and time-invariant system (**with real-valued impulse response $h[n]$**) always be exactly the same as the phase angles of the zeroes and poles of the system function $H(z)$ (i.e. Z-transform) of the LTI system?

If they do, please give a sketch of proof. If they don't, please give a counter example.

For example, if a zero (i.e. root) of the system function (i.e. Z-transform of the real-valued impulse response function) is $r_0*e^{j \omega_0}$ ($r_0\neq1$), then will $|H(e^{j \omega_0})|$ be a local minimum for the magnitude response function $|H(e^{j \omega})|$?

Similarly, if a pole of the system function is $r_0*e^{j \omega_0}$ ($r_0\neq1$), then will $|H(e^{j \omega_0})|$ be a local maximum of the magnitude response function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.